# How do I add a field to an Algolia index without rebuilding the whole index?

Tags: algolia

I'm adding a additional property to my objects that search clients will need. Is it possible to add this as a field on my Algolia objects without clearing and rebuilding the whole index? The field does not have to be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're just looking for the [`partial_update_object` and `partial_update_objects`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/indexing#partial-update-objects) methods.

In Ruby, here's how you'd use them (extracted from the documentation):

> ```ruby
> index.partial_update_object({"city" => "San Francisco", 
>                              "objectID" => "myID"})
> # or
> res = index.partial_update_objects([{"firstname" => "Jimmie", 
>                                      "objectID" => "SFO"},
>                                     {"firstname" => "Warren", 
>                                      "objectID" => "myID2"}])
> ```